# target ="_blank" automatically added in email

Tags: hyperlink, anchor

I am trying to send a newsletter containing multiple links and anchors to navigate through the page. Usually this works fine but the links no longer work now and open a new page instead (my mailbox).
I've noticed that the code of my links in the original page:

```
<a class="western" href="#Menu">Menu</a>
```

is automatically turned into the following in the email received :

```
<a class="western" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" href="#Menu">Menu</a>
```

Any idea what might be causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different e-mail clients support different HTML features.

Anchor links, for example, [are not very well supported at all](https://www.caniemail.com/features/html-anchor-links/).

An e-mail client can display your HTML in any way it wants: filtered, modified or even not at all. It's out of your hands, in this case.